# Number of Islands problem on leetcode - incorrect answer on leetcode but correct locally

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying this solution for the number of islands problem on leetcode.

```
class Solution:
islands = 0
visited = []
def numIslands(self, grid: list[list[str]]) -> int:
    self.islands = 0
    islands = [  ]
    _grid = [ row[:] for row in grid ]
    for r, row in enumerate(grid):
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            if grid[r][c] == "1":
                islands.append( (r, c) )
    for island in islands:
        self.dfs(_grid, island, ignore=True)
            
    return self.islands

def dfs(self, grid: list[list[str]], island, ignore=False):
    if island in self.visited: return 
    row, col = island

    if ignore and grid[row][col] == "1": 
        self.islands += 1
        print("incrementing")
    if grid[row][col] == "1":
        if not ignore: 
            grid[row][col] = "0"

        print((row,col), "ignore = ", ignore)
        self.visited.append((row,col))
    
        if row + 1 < len(grid):
            self.dfs(grid, (row+1, col))
        if col + 1 < len(grid[0]):
            self.dfs(grid, (row, col+1))
        if row -1 >= 0:
            self.dfs(grid, (row -1,col))
        if col - 1 >= 0:
            self.dfs(grid, (row, col-1))
```

When I run it locally(m1 mac python version 3.9.10) on the test input:

```
grid = [
 ["1","1","0","0","0"],
 ["1","1","0","0","0"],
 ["0","0","1","0","0"],
 ["0","0","0","1","1"]
 ]
```

I get the correct number of islands(3), whereas, in leetcode, it says that my solution only returns 2 as the number of islands.

I don't know what maybe causing this issue, and i thought it had something to do with inplace modification of the grid but that doesn't seem to be the case either since i made a deep copy of the original

Comment: Maybe leetcode imports the `Solution` class once, and calls `Solution().numIslands(...)` multiple times in the same process, in which case the `visited` class attribute will only be empty before the first test case, and for the second test case will not be reset. Try adding a `self.visited = []` at the top of the `numIslands` method.

Comment: If @Oli suggestion doesn't work then posting a link to the leetcode question would help

Answer (score 1):

Your solution keeps global state in the static variables outside of your two methods: when the LeetCode harness runs, these variables contaminate later tests.

```
2,3d1
<     islands = 0
<     visited = []
5c3
<         self.islands = 0
---
>         self.islands_count = 0
13c11
<             self.dfs(_grid, island, ignore=True)
---
>             self.dfs(_grid, island, True, [])
15c13
<         return self.islands
---
>         return self.islands_count
17,18c15,16
<     def dfs(self, grid: list[list[str]], island, ignore=False):
<         if island in self.visited: return
---
>     def dfs(self, grid: list[list[str]], island, ignore, visited):
>         if island in visited: return
22c20
<             self.islands += 1
---
>             self.islands_count += 1
29c27
<             self.visited.append((row,col))
---
>             visited.append((row,col))
32c30
<                 self.dfs(grid, (row+1, col))
---
>                 self.dfs(grid, (row+1, col), False, visited)
34c32
<                 self.dfs(grid, (row, col+1))
---
>                 self.dfs(grid, (row, col+1), False, visited)
36c34
<                 self.dfs(grid, (row -1,col))
---
>                 self.dfs(grid, (row -1,col), False, visited)
38c36
<                 self.dfs(grid, (row, col-1))
\ No newline at end of file
---
>                 self.dfs(grid, (row, col-1), False, visited)
\ No newline at end of file
```

I messily threw together this version of the solution which gets accepted at 825ms runtime.